# How to implement addressable LEDs with clock in/out with STM32

Tags: stm32, spi, serial, led-strip

I'm extremely new to embedded programming and have to figure out a way to control [this specific RGB strip](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/harvatek-corporation/T3A33BRG-H9C0002X1U1930/15930508) with an STM32 microcontroller.

[image: LED PINOUT]

Here is the communication protocol.

[image]

I don't know how to approach writing the code. Is the communication protocol SPI? It looks like SPI, but it doesn't have a chip select pin. Should I use my own protocol by using GPIO pins and bit banging? I could do that, but I read that method is significantly slower and more time consuming.

Comment: `Should I use my own protocol by using GPIO pins and bit banging?` ... yes, start with that ... that will confirm, or deny what you read

Comment: You are not forced to use chip select with SPI. There is no reason to bit bang.

Comment: yes, it's the same as SPI if you ignore the chip select. Lots of things are basically SPI.

Comment: ok thanks a lot guys ill implement it using the SPI protocol